# java.sql.SQLException: No Suitable Driver error in android app that interacts with postgres

Tags: java, android, sql, postgresql, jdbc

i'm following a tutorial that connects an Android App to a PostgresSQL db, the tutorial is here http://appliedcoffeetechnology.tumblr.com/post/10657124340 and then i have the following code:

```
package com.example.helllopostgresql;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HelloPostgreSQLActivity extends Activity {
    TextView resultArea;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        resultArea = new TextView(this);
        resultArea.setText("Please wait.");
        setContentView(resultArea);
        new FetchSQL().execute();
    }
    private class FetchSQL extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String retval = "";
            try {
                Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                retval = e.toString();
            }
            String url = "jdbc:postgresql://10.0.2.2/dbname?user=username&password=pass";
            Connection conn;
            try {
                DriverManager.setLoginTimeout(5);
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
                Statement st = conn.createStatement();
                String sql;
                sql = "SELECT 1";
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
                while(rs.next()) {
                    retval = rs.getString(1);
                }
                rs.close();
                st.close();
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                retval = e.toString();
            }
            return retval;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String value) {
            resultArea.setText(value);
        }
    }
}
```

The app starts normally but after the "Please Wait..." appears the error java.sql.SQLException: No Suitable Driver
Of course i imported the jar file with the libraries and ADT recognizes them because i can see the libraries in the structure of the project in "Referenced Libraries".
I read over the web that the error is typically a problem when there isn't the part "Class.forName ("org.postgresql.Driver")" . Of course i changed all the parameters in the url string that you can see in the code. 
What can i do? I really don't know what to do because i checked all the possible problems but it seems that i can't fix this issue, and it seems that i'm doing all correctly, i also tried the full copy/paste from the site that i linked!...Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved the problem! It was my fault that when i add the external jar to the libraries it was in a path outside the project folder! (The main fault however is of Eclipse that compile the project :-D ) I copy and paste the .jar with libraries under the libs directory and i don't have the error anymore!
Thanks to all!

Answer (score 1):

Did you check for the jar file to be present in that referenced place.

Comment: Yes of course like I told in my post the library appears correctly under referenced and it works also fine because adt detects it and then it offers to me suggestions when I'm writing the code!